# How to get C# to recognize argument passed through PowerShell

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, development, powershell, alert

I'm using PowerShell to call C# code to turn list alerts on or off on a specific list. When I try to use `[AlertsOnOff1.onOff]::Main("off")` to call the Main method and pass the arugment of "off"the script runs like everything went fine with zero errors, but when I create an item on the list I still get Alerts. How can I get the C# code to recognize the argument passed by PowerShell?

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

$path = "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI"

$Assem = @(
    "$path\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll",
    "System.Core"
         )

$Source = @"
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;
using System.IO;

namespace AlertsOnOff1
{
    public class onOff
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            args = new string[1];
            string site = "http://intranet.contoso.com/";
            string web = string.Empty;
            string list = "ListA";
            SPSite tmpSite=null;

            try
            {

                tmpSite = new SPSite(site);
                SPWeb tmpWeb = tmpSite.OpenWeb(web);
                SPList tmpList = tmpWeb.Lists[list];

                foreach (SPAlert tmpAlert in tmpWeb.Alerts)
                {

                    if (args[0] == "on") //Turn it ON
                    {
                        if ((tmpAlert.List.Title == tmpList.Title) & (tmpAlert.Status == SPAlertStatus.Off))
                        {
                            tmpAlert.Status = SPAlertStatus.On;
                            tmpAlert.Update();
                        }
                    }

                    if (args[0] == "off") //Turn it OFF
                    {
                        if ((tmpAlert.List.Title == tmpList.Title) & (tmpAlert.Status == SPAlertStatus.On))
                        {
                            tmpAlert.Status = SPAlertStatus.Off;
                            tmpAlert.Update();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
                System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("Disable/Enable Alerts", ex.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            finally
            {
                //Dispose of the Root Site Object
                tmpSite.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source -ReferencedAssemblies $Assem

Write-Host "Turning alerts off"
[AlertsOnOff1.onOff]::Main("off")
Write-Host "Alerts turned off"

#powershell code
```

Update:

Originally when I didn't have `args = new string[1];` I would get an error when i passed an argument through the C# code. I have now removed that line of code and passing the argument works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method expects an array of strings, but you are passing in a single string.

Also, the first line of your method overwrites the value that was passed in (perhaps you added this because you were getting an error?)

I would suggest changing the method signature to

```
public static void Main(string args)
```

and also removing the following line of code:

```
args = new string[1];
```

Comment: When I change to `public static void Main(string args)` I get an error stating that `'AlertsOnOff1.onOff.Main(string)' has the wrong signature to be an entry point`

Comment: I see what mean by `args = string[0]; overwriting the argument. I ended up removing the line and now my code is working. Although before I had the line of code, my code was throwing an error.

Comment: Okay - sounds like a requirement that the parameter be an array - good to hear you got it sorted anyway.